# PHP strips out JSON node (array)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to log some stuff in a JSON file.

An entry looks like this:

```
    {
        "bookindId":"30779265",
        "timestamp":"1428447744",
        "plate":"D-GO9872",
        "cityId":"RLD",
        "zoneId":"759",
        "highDemandZones":[
            "402",
            "429",
            "714",
            "715",
            "721",
            "728",
            "732",
            "734",
            "742",
            "756",
            "758",
            "763"
        ],
        "accountId":"151426",
        "date":"20150408",
        "formattedDate":"08.04.2015, 01:02 Uhr"
    },
```

But sometimes, `highDemandZones` is just missing:

```
    {
        "bookindId":"30779279",
        "timestamp":"1428447762",
        "plate":"D-GO120",
        "cityId":"RLD",
        "zoneId":"759",
        "accountId":"151426",
        "date":"20150408",
        "formattedDate":"08.04.2015, 01:02 Uhr"
    },
```

My problem is that even if there aren't any `highDemandZones`, it should at least be in there as an empty array. Also I can defenitely say that it shouldn't be empty either. Which leads me to the conclusion that my php code is flawed.

This is the javascript function

```
App.prototype.trackBooking = function() {

    var self = this;

    // [... stripped out other code for clarity]

    // get high demand zones
    var highDemandZones = [];
    $.each(this.model.zoneDemands, function(id, details) {
        if(details.demand == 'HIGH') {
            highDemandZones.push(id);
        }
    });

    // [... stripped out other code for clarity]

    var obj = {

        bookindId: this.model.user.booking.bookingId,
        timestamp: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000),
        plate: this.model.user.booking.vehicle.numberPlate,
        cityId: this.model.city.id,
        zoneId: car.zoneId,
        highDemandZones: highDemandZones,
        accountId: this.model.user.accountId,
        date: todayFormatted,
        formattedDate: day + '.' + month + '.' + year + ', ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ' Uhr'

    };

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'php/ajax.php',
        data: {
            booking: obj,
            action: 'trackBooking'
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log('TRACKED');
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    });

};
```

This is php function that'll save this `obj` to a JSON file

```
function saveBooking($booking) {


    // get current bookings
    $json = file_get_contents("../reporting/bookings.json");
    $bookingsArr = json_decode($json, true);


    if(!isset($bookingsArr[$booking['date']])) {
        $bookingsArr[$booking['date']] = array();
    }

    // push new booking into current bookings array
    array_push($bookingsArr[$booking['date']], $booking);

    // convert to JSON
    $jsonString = json_encode($bookingsArr);

    // save into JSON file
    file_put_contents('../reporting/bookings.json', $jsonString);

    // return JSON
    echo $jsonString;

}
```

Do you have any ideas when this could occur? The IDs (the strings inside `highDemandZones`) never have extended characters like é.
There are defenitely nodes being stripped out even though the array is not empty. The JSON is valid.

Comment: Spy the communication between js and php, i doubt that the json_decode function is responsible for that.

Comment: just to clarify: This is happening on our live server - I was not able to reproduce this locally yet. I just see the JSON missing these nodes and our backend data.

Comment: Then you can trace the input (in a log file) of the json_decode function, to see if it's really responsible for that.

Comment: (Or much better, trace the input only if the highDemandZones key is missing)

Comment: ok I'm logging everything now:

`$date = date('Ymd');
    $phpArrAsString = print_r($booking, true);
    file_put_contents($date.'.txt', $phpArrAsString.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);`

Let's see if I can narrow this down to a function

Comment: i would log the `$json`variable...

Comment: `if(!isset($bookingsArr['highDemandZones'])) file_put_contents(date('Ymd').'.txt', $json.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: (this way you'll just have the traces corresponding to the input json responsible for the problem...)

Comment: I added it as well. But I think if that file is created it means that the object passed from JS isn't having the `highDemandZones` node. We'll see over the next few days.